# Why do `vector` and `[...]` sometimes behave differently in Clojure?

Tags: vector, syntax, clojure, syntactic-sugar

In Clojure, the square brackets are a shorthand for defining vectors:

```
user=> (vector 'a 'b 'c)
[a b c]
user=> ['a 'b 'c]
[a b c]
```

[The documentation page](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector) for `vector` speaks of the long way and the short way of defining vectors.

However, in `defn` and `doseq` there seems to be a difference.

```
user=> (doseq [x (range 1 4)] (printf "%d\n" x)) 
1
2
3
nil
user=> (doseq (vector 'x (range 1 4)) (printf "%d\n" x)) 
IllegalArgumentException doseq requires a vector for its binding in user:1 clojure.core/doseq (core.clj:2935)
```

What accounts for this difference? Are the square brackets given special status in the reader, or do they sugar some particular form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vector` is evaluated after macroexpansion, while `[]` is evaluated at read time, before macros are expanded. In your second case, the `doseq` macro does not see a vector, it sees a list starting with the symbol `vector`, since macros are expanded before regular functions are evaluated.